# Launch google now into listen mode by holding home button like in iOS

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, google-now, voice-recognition, voice-command, home-button

I just switched from iOS to android 5.0. With Siri, you are able to hold the home button (from the lock screen or otherwise) and it will immediately start listening for a command. I would like this same behavior with Google Now.

I realize you can set your phone to be listen for the "OK Google" initiation command. That is **not** what I want. I hate having to do that. I want to activate voice commands by holding the home button.
Is this possible?

Please any help would be appreciated!